# How to make child stay within scrollable a parent

Tags: css

I'm trying to setup a parent > child relationship, in which the parent is scrollable but the child does not scroll and stays fixed at top 50%.

I have tried using multiple positions and means of separating the child from the parent but it is important that this relationship stays the same. This is for a mega-menu in which the main list is very long and should scroll on the left-side, but the secondary-level, as it is shorter, when shown should stay top centred and not scroll with the parent so that it is always in view

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.nothing {
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  border: solid 1px red;
  height: 256px;
  width: 256px;
  overflow: scroll;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 16px;
}

.inner {
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.full-height {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 0;
  right: 128px;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="full-height">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="nothing">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="inner">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur mollitia maxime facere quae cumque perferendis cum atque quia repellendus rerum eaque quod quibusdam incidunt blanditiis possimus temporibus reiciendis deserunt sequi eveniet necessitatibus
      maiores quas assumenda voluptate qui odio laboriosam totam repudiandae? Doloremque dignissimos voluptatibus eveniet rem quasi minus ex cumque esse culpa cupiditate cum architecto! Facilis deleniti unde suscipit minima obcaecati vero ea soluta odio
      cupiditate placeat vitae nesciunt quis alias dolorum nemo sint facere. Deleniti itaque incidunt eligendi qui nemo corporis ducimus beatae consequatur est iusto dolorum consequuntur vero debitis saepe voluptatem impedit sint ea numquam quia voluptate
      quidem.
      <div class="full-height"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the example, I'd like to know how to get the text to be scrollable but the blue box to stay centred within the initial viewport.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to have a wrapper (`.nothing`, what you used) and that contains the scollable div and the element that should "stay".

http://jsfiddle.net/muexontb/1/

The other solution would be to use `position: sticky`.

Comment: I see what you mean but I need .full-height to be inside of .inner

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll ultimately want to clean this up a little, but `position: sticky` is what you want:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.nothing {
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  border: solid 1px red;
  height: 256px;
  width: 256px;
  overflow: scroll;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 16px;
}

.inner {
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.full-height {
  position: sticky;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 0;
  width: calc(100% - 128px);
  bottom: 0;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="full-height">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="nothing">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="full-height"></div>
    <div class="inner">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur mollitia maxime facere quae cumque perferendis cum atque quia repellendus rerum eaque quod quibusdam incidunt blanditiis possimus temporibus reiciendis deserunt sequi eveniet necessitatibus
      maiores quas assumenda voluptate qui odio laboriosam totam repudiandae? Doloremque dignissimos voluptatibus eveniet rem quasi minus ex cumque esse culpa cupiditate cum architecto! Facilis deleniti unde suscipit minima obcaecati vero ea soluta odio
      cupiditate placeat vitae nesciunt quis alias dolorum nemo sint facere. Deleniti itaque incidunt eligendi qui nemo corporis ducimus beatae consequatur est iusto dolorum consequuntur vero debitis saepe voluptatem impedit sint ea numquam quia voluptate
      quidem.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You cannot easily have the "sticky" element inside the "inner" element because it is not what is scrolling - consider explaining why do you need it like that.